# Como fazer com que auma função seja executada após uma outra? JS (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Tenho as seguints funções:

Pega dados do servidor por ajax e salva em um Array de objetos:

```html
function carregaPesquisaTabela(){
 controlLoading();
 $.ajax({
 url: "header.php",
 type: "POST",
 dataType:"json",
 data: {
  'procuraPesquisa' : null
 }
 
}).done(function(data){
  pesquisaObj = data;
  controlLoading();
});

}
```

Pega o Array de Objetos e monta uma tabela. (Não vou colocar todo o código porque não é necessário)

```html
function montaTabela(){
 $("#tablePesquisas").empty();
 var linha = "";
 for(i = 0; i<pesquisaObj.length; i++){
  //Monta dados e insere em uma tabela 
 $("#tablePesquisas").html(linha);
  }
}
```

Chamo as duas da seguinte maneira:

```html
$("#viewPesquisa").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
carregaPesquisaTabela();
montaTabela();
});
```

O problema é que a ação montaTabela(); está acontecendo antes da função carregaPesquisaTabela(); estar finalizada, e por isso o resultado não está sendo real.

Vi algo sobre callback mas não consegui implementar. O que fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está vendo aquela função que você declara no `.done()` do jQuery? Aquilo é o callback, a função que você passa para o jQuery invocar quando ele obter o resultado.

O que você quer é chamar montaTabela via done, ou seja:

```
function carregaPesquisaTabela(){
    controlLoading();
    $.ajax({
        url: "header.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            'procuraPesquisa' : null
        }

    }).done(function(data){
        pesquisaObj = data;
        controlLoading();
        montaTabela();
    });
}
```

Vou aproveitar para mencionar um detalhe: em montaTabela você está usando `.html()` para anexar mais linhas a sua tabela, mas `.html()` substitui todo o conteúdo já existente, o que você precisa é `.append()`.

**--Edit--**

Enviando seu próprio callback:

Em resposta ao comentário, também o possível enviar sua própria função para ser chamada ao término do AJAX.

```
function carregaPesquisaTabela(callback){
    controlLoading();
    $.ajax({
        url: "header.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            'procuraPesquisa' : null
        }

    }).done(function(data){
        pesquisaObj = data;
        controlLoading();
        if (callback) { /*se nada for enviado, esse if não é executado*/
            callback();
        }
    });
}

$("#viewPesquisa").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    carregaPesquisaTabela(montaTabela);
});
```

Comment: Então, oq eue acontece é que queria que a minha função carregaPesquisaTabela(), pudesse ser chamada para buscar os dados e uma outra função para trata los, por exemplo, coloca-los em uma tabela ou em um option de um select. E evitar ter que duplicar o código de busca no servidor.

Comment: Ok, tente a correção que eu fiz.

Comment: Great! Exatamente o que eu precisava. Funcionando perfeitamente! Obrigado!